# Redis-objects list on a Redis-object in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, redis-objects

I have a redis-object's list. Each object in the list needs to have another list.

`class Parent
  include Redis::Objects
  list :children, marshal: true
end`

`class children
  include Redis::Objects
end`

The above code samples just highlight the relationship. They do include other things like attr_accessors etc.

My issue arrives when I call children on an instance of the parent, such as in the example below:

`p = Parent.new`

`Redis::List.new('some_key', marshal: true) << p`

`p.children
=> nil`

I have a working example using an active record model with the list added to it. However including it on a redis-object seems to give me issues.

Do I need to handle the situation manually in the way it is described in part two of the redis-object documentation, or do I some how have to create the redis-objects list on creation of the parent object? My thoughts were that this creation was implicit

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I had an attr_accessor on the parent, named children. This clashed with the list defined with the name children. Removing the attr_accessor resulted in the an empty redis-objects list being returned, which was the expected behavior.